# Split SQL field containing array into new table/rows

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, join, string-matching

I need a list of user IDs (`course_user_id`s) that is currently stored in a single field of a larger table.

I have a table called `courses` that contains course information with `course_id` and `course_students` as such:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| course_id | course_students                             |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | a:3:{i:0;i:12345;i:1;i:22345;i:2;i:323456;} |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 2         | a:32:{ … }                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The `course_students` part contains 3 chunks of information:

1. the number of students (a:**3**:{…) -- not needed
2. the order/key for the array of each student ({i:**0**;… i:**1**;… i:**2**; …}) -- also not needed
3. the `course_user_id` (i:**12345**; … i:**22345**;… i:**32345**;)

I only need the `course_user_id` and the original `course_id`, resulting in a new table that i can use for joins/subqueries like this:

```
------------------------------
| course_id | course_user_id |
------------------------------
| 1         | 12345          |
------------------------------
| 1         | 22345          |
------------------------------
| 1         | 323456         |
------------------------------
```

(ideally able to continue to break out values for other `course_id`s and `course_user_id`s, but not a priority:)

```
| …         | …              |
------------------------------
| 2         | …              |
------------------------------
| 2         | …              |
------------------------------
| 97        | …              |
------------------------------
| 97        | …              |
------------------------------
| …         | …              |
------------------------------
```

Note: the `course_user_id` can vary in length (some are 5 digits, some are 6)

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

### Update

My user table does have `user_id` which can be mapped to `course_students` or `course_user_id`, so that is a very helpful observation from below.

I also think I need to use a `LEFT JOIN` because some students are registered in multiple courses, and I'd like to see each instance/combo.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this with pure SQL. Can you use a scripting language (for example, Pithon or PHP)?

Comment: @Barranka : You are predicting too early..  ;)

Comment: Kindly update question with details of user table.

Comment: One quirk is that the registration key in the array (low numbers from 0 to 100, typically) can also correspond with users in my user table. But all our users have more recent accounts so I can manually filter out the low numbers. Would there be a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you have a table name `users` which contains all users data along with `user_id`.

Now you can join table `courses` and table `users` in following manner:

```
select c.course_id,u.user_id

from
courses c
join users u
on u.user_id=if(instr(c.course_students,concat(":",u.user_id,";"))>0,u.user_id,c.course_students)
```

You get the result as per your requirement.
Verify at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3667d/2

Note: The above query works fine if no overlapping between `user_id` and `array index`. In case of overlapping, kindly filter data using `where-clause`

Comment: I tried this and it mostly worked. It also included the array index numbers (like 1 - 50 in most cases) but I could filter those out with a WHEN u.user_id > 1000 (as far as I can tell most usernames are larger than ~ 2000).

Comment: @TigheFlanagan : As `users` table contains `user_id` greater than 1000 and array index is smaller than 50, the query will not include unnecessary data. If there is overlapping between `user_id` and `array index`, you have to filter out unnecessary data using `group by c.course_id`.

Comment: This works and returns results pretty quickly, but must manually fiter out noise (the low numbers that also are in the user.user_id column). My working example is here http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/5064

Answer (score 0):

If I got your goal correctly you have `users` table. And `{i:0;i:12345;i:1;i:22345;i:2;i:323456;` equal `users.id=12345`,`users.id=22345` etc.

If my guess is correct you can try this solution:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfef27/5

```
SELECT * FROM courses
LEFT JOIN users u
ON courses.course_students LIKE CONCAT('%i:',u.id,';%')
```

Comment: I used the LEFT JOIN because students are (often) in multiple courses. I haven't tried your ON condition yet, but will see if that also works (comparing to the previous suggestion). Thanks!

Comment: This worked, but with a lot more noise and null returns.

Comment: @tgf84 what do you call noise? :-) extra fields? so just call what you need like `SELECT c.course_id, u.id FROM courses c...` :-) there is absolutely no noise :-)